# Blockchair - dump files does not contain decimal bitcoin values

Tags: blockchain

I hope this is the correct place to ask this.

I have downloaded a dump file from Blockchair containing blockchain transactions. Everything looks fine, but the decimal separator is removed in the values for the amount of bitcoins.

For example:

This is the real amount of btc: 0.00253658

This is what the dump file shows: 253658

Hash link: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/16fbf725fab270860323cca7a16c71002af2c419b067dc0787e7ab461811d35a

Dump file row:
[image]

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: What does the API documentation say is the format of the transaction amount? Maybe they prescale it.

Answer (score 1):

Someone on another forum gave me the answer: the result in the dump file is given in Statoshi, not bitcoin. 1 Satoshi = 1e10^(-8) BTC.